# Would this be a valid proof for linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

The question is a series of questions but this part gives an equation where A is a 3x3 nilpotent matrix with an index of nilpotence $k$ of 3 so that $A^k = 0$ and  $A\vec{x}$ and $A^2\vec{x}$ is non-zero. I need to prove that the vectors $\vec{x}, A\vec{x}$ and $A^2\vec{x}$ so that I can extend it to a general nilpotent matrix of $n$ x $n$ with an index $k$ and show that $k\leq n$. I'm not allowed to use any theories outside of linear independence so....
$$
\lambda_1\vec{x} + \lambda_2A\vec{x} + \lambda_3A^2\vec{x}= \vec{0}
\\
\lambda_1A\vec{x} + \lambda_2A^2\vec{x} + \lambda_3A^3\vec{x}= \vec{0}
\\
\lambda_1A\vec{x} + \lambda_2A^2\vec{x} = \vec{0}
$$
Would it be valid to show linear independence of $A\vec{x}$ and $A^2\vec{x}$ by the following method? Since $-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}A \neq A^2$
$$
\lambda_1A\vec{x} = -\lambda_2A^2\vec{x}
\\
-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}A\vec{x}=A^2\vec{x}
$$
This proof seems iffy but I have no idea how to prove it otherwise. Would appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: What are you trying to prove? The linear independence of **what**?

Comment: My bad, linear independence of $A\vec{x}$ and $A^2\vec{x}$

Comment: The fact that there are constants $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1v+\lambda_2w=0$ shows that $v,w$ are not independent (unless the constants are zero).

Comment: (i) You have omitted "are L.I."  in your statement I think.

Comment: (ii) You had one excellent idea, "multiply by $A$". Why stop there? Why not do it again?

Comment: That's actually genius, I... Uh am amazed why I didn't think of that. Thanks so much. @ancientmathematician

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not OK. First of all, it is all symbols, and very little text. You should always write proofs in such a way that they can be read out loud. With full sentences, and text explaining what each equation means. Most proofs include the words "let", "therefore", "implies" and the like.

Second of all, two logical errors you make are:

1. You assert that $-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}A\neq A^2$. How do you know this is true?
2. The fact that $-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}A\neq A^2$ is not enough to conclude, for some vector $x$, that $-\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}Ax\neq A^2x.$ It is perfectly possible for two non-equal matrices to act identically on one particular vector.

Finally, your proof is not OK because the very statement you are trying to prove is false. For example, if $A=I$, then $Ax$ and $A^2x$ will never be independent.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Of course. Thanks for catching that typo.

Comment: Hmm, thanks but there was a detail I left out because I assumed it didn't add any information. What if the $A$ is actually a non-zero nilpotent matrix with an index of 3. Would that change anything? Sorry I'm pretty new to linear algebra.

Comment: @Fluryy What does "with an index of 3" mean? Also, if you added information, add it to your original post, not just in some comment on some answer. You want a newcomer to the question to see that same info.

Comment: Sorry, I've added all the information I was withholding.